# Induction proof without summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

I have to prove this induction:

$\dfrac{1}{(n+1)}+\dfrac{1}{(n+2)}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{2n} = \dfrac{1}{(1\times2)}+\dfrac{1}{(3\times4)}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)\times2n}$

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, but I didn't know how to create the right 'summation mark' for each of those equations.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I see that you have [added sequences-and-series tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1615022/revisions). AFAIK for finite sums (summation) is more appropriate. See the relevant discussions on meta [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6324/summation-tag-for-finite-and-formal-summations) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/when-using-summation-tag-should-we-remove-sequences-and-series).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I thought it was not irrelevant to add this tag here. But please, feel free to remove the tag if you find it inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the summation symbol, note that
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n}=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}
$$
Therefore
$$
a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{n+1+k}
$$
The right-hand side can be written
$$
b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}
$$
So your task is to prove $a_n=b_n$. The case $n=1$ is trivial. Suppose the assertion holds for $n$. Then
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{n+1+k}\\[6px]
{\scriptsize\text{(add and subtract, detach two terms)}\quad}
&=-\frac{1}{n+1}+\biggl(\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n+1+k}\biggr)+
\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}\\[6px]
{\scriptsize\text{(set $l=k+1$)}\quad}
&=-\frac{1}{n+1}+\biggl(\,\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+l}\biggr)+
\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}\\[6px]
{\scriptsize\text{(induction hypothesis)}\quad}
&=-\frac{1}{n+1}+b_n+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}\\[6px]
{\scriptsize\text{(rearrange)}\quad}
&=b_n+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\\[6px]
&=b_n+\frac{2n+2-2n-1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\[6px]
&=b_n+\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\[6px]
&=b_{n+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. You may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac1{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{2(n+1)}\right)-\left(\frac1{n+1}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}\right)&=-\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2(n+1)}\\\\
&=-\frac1{2(n+1)}+\frac1{2n+1}\\\\
&=\frac1{(2n+1)\times(2n+2)}.
\end{align}
$$